# Passing array values to each loop

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I am using a plugin that creates donut charts called easyPieChart. I need to update the data that is passed to the plugin. This is done by the following:

```
 $(this).data('easyPieChart').update(40);
```

This basically sets the value of the donut to 40%. I need to loop through a series of divs and update the donut charts in each one. If I was to do the following, all donuts would be updated to 40%:

```
$('.percentage').each(function() {
      $(this).data('easyPieChart').update(40);
});
```

I need to create an array of integers to pass, so as we are iterating on `.percentage` a different value is passed to each. So for instance, the first `.percentage` receives a value of 40, the second 60, etc.

if I had an array with all of the numbers, how would I use it with the each loop:

```
var numbToUse = [40,30,60];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `each` is the index, so you can use it to get it's value, like the following:

```
var numbToUse = [40,30,60];

$('.percentage').each(function(i) {
      $(this).data('easyPieChart').update(numToUse[i]);
});
```